# Dividing integer types - Are results predictable?

Tags: c#, integer-division

I have a 64-bit long that I want to round down to the nearest 10,000, so I am doing a simple:

```
long myLong = 123456789
long rounded = (myLong / 10000) * 10000; //rounded = 123450000
```

This appears to do what I expect, but as I'm not 100% on the internals of how integer types get divided, I am just slightly concerned that there may be situations where this doesn't work as expected.

Will this still work at very large numbers / edge cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work, so long as no result, intermediate or otherwise, exceeds `long.MaxValue`.

To be explicit about your constants you could use the `L` specifier at the end, e.g. `123456789L`.

For straightforward calculations like this, can I suggest Pex from Microsoft ( http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/ ), which looks for edge cases and tests them.  This is a clean-cut example, but if you were building up lots of logic based on things you are unsure of, it's a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work. The semantics of integer division guarantee what you expect.

However it may be good to write some tests for your specific use case, including edge cases. This will reassure you.