# With c++ integers, does 1 divided by 2 reliably equal 0, and 3/2 = 1, 5/2 = 2 etc.?

Tags: c++, integer-division

There are two vectors of differing, yet related sizes. The larger is `(2 * RESOLUTION) + INDEX_OFFSET` (e.g. 2050) and the smaller is simply `RESOLUTION` (e.g. 1024). I believe it safe enough to assume that `uint16_t` can be used to contain the vector index.

Iteration through the larger vector is performed by incrementing `resultIndex` by 2. During each iteration, an assignment is made to the smaller vector at the index `(resultIndex - INDEX_OFFSET) / 2`.

Essentially, the code relies on the assumption that, whether `INDEX_OFFSET` is odd or even, the above division by 2 will always round down, regardless of architecture. For example, if `resultIndex` is 0 or 1, then 0 is expected, if is it 2 or 3 then 1 is expected, and so on. Is this a safe assumption, within the parameters above?

N.B. I acknowledge the existence of ['Dividing integer types - Are results predictable?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064447/dividing-integer-types-are-results-predictable) but it does not seem to be an exact match.

Comment: well as always `2+2 = 5` in very large cases of 2

Comment: @Woot4Moo: snarky can be fun, but in this case it's just dumb. Integral division has very specific rules regarding truncation, and the fact is that `3/2 == 1`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes; this is guaranteed by the language:

> `[C++11: 5.6/4]:` The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined. **For integral operands the `/` operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;** if the quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a`.

In `3/2`, both `3` and `2` are integral operands; the algebraic quotient of this operation is `1.5`, and when you discard the fractional part `.5`, you get `1`. This holds for your other examples and, well, all other examples.

Comment: +1, and thank God this is standard. I can't *imagine* the amount of f'ed up code out there were it not.

Comment: Note: on linux => `signal 5: arithmetic exception` is usually the result of a division by `0` that is *executed*... though since the compiler may optimize the code on the assumption that the divider not being `0`, weird things may happen (aka "undefined behavior").