# SQL Server Implicit Data Type Conversion Challenges

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've worked with many databases over the last 20 yrs and have only ran into this "interesting" type of implicit data conversion problem with SQL Server.

If i create a table with one small int column and insert two rows with a value 1 and 2 into it and then run the following query "Select Avg(Column) From table" i get a truncated result instead of the 1.5 that i would get from pretty much any other dB on the planet that would automatically upsize the datatype to store the entire results rather than truncating/rounding to the columns data type.  Now i know i can cast my way around this for every possible scenario but not a good dynamic solution especially for data analytics with data analytic products... I.E: Cognos/Microstrategy etc...

I am in data warehousing and have fact tables with millions of rows in them... I would love to store small columns and have proper aggregation results.  My current approach to work around this nuance is to define the smallest quantifiable columns as Numeric(19,5) to account for all situations even though these columns many times only store 1 or 0 for which a tinyint would be great but will not naturally aggregate well.

Is there not any directive that tells SQL server do do what every other DB (oracle/db2/informix/access etc...) does?   Which is promote to a larger type and show the entire results and let me do what i want with them?

Comment: Have you considered adding a calculated column that you can use in your aggregates? `ColumnN as cast(Column as numeric(19, 5)))`. It will not take up any space in the table but has to do the conversion in the queries and that takes some extra time.

Comment: Sorry but yes the performance overhead on DW fact tables is not something we want across millions of rows of data, as well as the overhead of having to maintain 2 columns for each quantitative value.  I think it is coming to a head... for BI/EDW purposes one cannot utilize SQL Servers small data type values (Byte, TinyInt, SmallInt,Int) and expect summary/aggregate SQL functions to produce accurate results by default.  I think this is a major design oversight in the dB Engine and it certainly renders most of their numeric types useless for clean adhoc analytic purposes.

Comment: If you have a lot of rows you may also run into the issue that SQL Server internally uses `sum(col)/count(*)` to calculate `avg()`. The internal `sum()` part will fail if your sum exceeds the limit for `int`. To be in the safe side from that happening you need to cast the value in the `avg()` to `bigint`. If you instead cast to `numeric(38, 0)` you will also retrieve a correct average value as a `numeric(36, 6)`. There is less overhead in using the cast in the query than using a calculated column.

Comment: Thx Michael yep we have run into this... Appreciate the warning though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create views on the tables which would cast the `smallint` or `tinyint` to `float` and only publish these views to the users. This would keep the small memory usage. The conversion should be no overhead, compared to other database systems that must do that as well if they use a different data type for aggregation.

Comment: I'm using Star schemas Facts/Dimensions etc... that have millions of rows and you don't want everything being a cast on the fly as it is a significant performance overhead since it is not part of the engine....  Again i was really looking to see if there was any type of directive that allows SQL Server to behave like virtually every other serious RDBMS does...

Comment: Have you tested the performance impact? Or do you just assume this impact? Actually, it may be faster doing an on-the fly conversion in memory than e. g. increasing I/O by increasing the physical size of the column.

Answer (score 1):

While it might frustrate you, a lot of programming languages also behave this way with ints, `1 / 2` will spit out `0`. See:

[With c++ integers, does 1 divided by 2 reliably equal 0, and 3/2 = 1, 5/2 = 2 etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282989/with-c-integers-does-1-divided-by-2-reliably-equal-0-and-3-2-1-5-2-2-et)

It's a design quirk, it'd break a lot of things if they changed it. You're asking can you change a fairly fundamental way SQL Server behaves and thus potentially break any one else's code running on the server.

Simply put, no you can't.

And you're wrong that every other DB product behaves this way, Derby also does the same thing:

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32693.html

In the Oracle docs they specifically warn you that AVG will return a float regardless of the original type. This is because every language has to make the choice, do I return the original type or the most precise answer? To stop overflows, a lot of languages chose the former to the constant frustration of programmers everywhere.

So in SQL Server, to get a float out, put a float in.

Comment: I know programming languages do this and that is ok( understood why because you have control over the machine)... Derby???  Really????  Let me name the others that don't do this... Oracle, Informix, DB2, Main Frame DB2, Redbrick, BigData, MS Access, FoxPro, Dbase...    For business intelligence this is highly irregular behavior... i now see why Microsofts BI Suite stores everything as numerics... rendering the smaller data types useless for dynamic query analysis from end users who don't know data types...

Comment: Stop ranting against SQL Server just because you don't like it's behaviour. All DBs have their quirks, this is one of theirs. Deal with it.

Comment: Ur the one defending it via the Derby comment...  I dont' mind SQL Server... as a serios DBA for Oracle and Informix to me its a bit toyish compared to the other engines but it works fairly well and MS gives u a ton of stuff with it 4 free... the admin is brain dead stuff... so it has its place... but finding advanced admin info is very tough and spotty... so i was thinking that someone somewhere might know a parameter directive similar to what informix offerred to let you control how implicit datatype conversions...  but instead i got workarounds i already knew about.

Comment: First off: you never mentioned which workarounds you already knew about, so you can hardly blame people for giving you those as an answer. Second: considering they're the only right answer, you could do with toning down the nasty attitude.

Comment: I did want to receive solutions outside of cast conversions.  Ultimately I learned SS implemented oddities like Count_big to deal with these issues. Other oddities... Sum will return the most precise data-type possible by default which is what you want. Avg will autocast to the parameter type passed removing precision by default which is goofy. Count/sum/avg/min/max are by default mathmatically precise in other DBMS regardless of storage datatype.  I was hoping for a db config centric approach which there isn't any.  I gave up all hope when i learned t-sql IsNumeric(',') = true

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, the fastest way would be to do an implicit cast: `SELECT AVG(Field * 1.0)`. You could of course do an explicit cast the same way. As far as I know there is no way to tell SQL Server that you want integers converted to floats when you average them, and arguably that's actually correct behavior.

Comment: To truncate a answer without being asked to do so because of a storage type is NOT arguably a correct answer.  Oracle, Informix, DB2, DB2, MS Access, FoxPro, Dbase, Redbrick all Upscale data types.  The rule of the db engine is to never "Guess" show everything and allow user to convert... And its not just about the AVG function when your doing dynamic analytics you never know what kind of query is going to get fired against a DB especially when your using tools like Cognos, MicroStrategy, Business Objects etc...  Again in my opinion this is a db design oversight.

Comment: Not to raise a discussion here, but it is basically what any programming language would do. In pseudo code: `int i = 12; print (i / 5);` should result in 2 being printed in nearly every language I know. SQL Server is taking the same mindset to the database level and from a programmer's standpoint this might be a defendable choice. Comparing it to other databases: not so much. This is why it's debatable. I don't care if you agree with me, but to some people this makes sense and I can't blame them.